# how do i get refresh token with each request?

Tags: objective-c, oauth-2.0, afnetworking-3

I am Communicating with .net api over server and now in api they are using oAuth2. So in ios i have to get refresh token every time i'm making request and in another request i have to pass this token. Its like "bearer TOKEN".I am using AFNetworking in my app. Any idea to get this thing working?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AFNetworking3 you will use HEAD request for getting refresh token. And then Fire your actual request on success block.

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [manager dataTaskWithHTTPMethod:@"HEAD" URLString:URLString parameters:parameters headerFields:headerFields success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, __unused id responseObject) {
    if (success) {
        success(task);
        // on success block you can fire your final API with below refresh token
         [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"Bearer RRFRESH_TOKEN" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
    }
} failure:failure];

[dataTask resume];
```

You and also create an operation object to perform both API which is more manageable and flexible.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the `AFHTTPSessionManager` class to make you requests, you could do the following before making the http request:

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"Bearer YOUR_TOKEN" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
```

Comment: Is that request will give the refresh token at same time with my response from api?

Comment: I think you need to perform separate requests, one to get the token, and another one that will need to use this token at the header

Comment: aahh thats what i dont want ... i' recursively requesting from server.. between thanks for help.